# Outlook Add-In: Detect when any of the CC or TO email addresses are selected

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, add-in

Basically I have an Outlook Add-In that when a new mail item is selected in the Explorer a callback is fired. In this callback, based on if the mail item is sent or received, I select the external email address (meaning the email address that does not belong the outlook account. If the mail item is of type received then I select the FROM address, otherwise I select the first TO address) and make an HTTP call to a RESTful API to obtain more info about the person based on that email address.

The point is that if the mail item has multiple CC's or multiple TO's, I need to be able to detect when any of this email address are selected, so I can make another call to the API with the selected email address.

Answer (score 0):

Recipient selection in emails is not exposed at all.